# Angularjs Click event handling within link

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make a custom directive which would show different buttons based on attribute present. One of the button requires click event handler and I want to handle it within the directive as there will be multiple instances of this directive in same page. I tried the code below but to no avail.

```
'use strict';
angular
    .module('test-template', [])
    .directive('testTemplateBricks', [
    '$compile',
    '$timeout',
        function($compile,$timeout) {
            return {
               restrict: 'A', 
                link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
                    var el = "";
                    if(iAttrs.needImg=="true")
                    {
                        el += '<input type="file" style="display:none;" class="browse-file"/><button class="btn btn-info" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" ng-click="browse()"></span></button>';
                    }
                    if(iAttrs.needTxt=="true")
                    {
                        el += ' <button class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>';
                    }

                    $compile(el)($scope);
                    iElm.append(el);

                    $scope.browse = function() { console.log("browsing");};

                    $timeout(function(){
                        iElm.on("click",function(e){
                            console.log("Browsing");
                            iElm.find("input[type=file]").click();
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

**EDIT**: http://plnkr.co/edit/bNRLvWjEE7LLvhwRFIae?p=preview

In this sample I want to display the hidden file browser when the image button is clicked.

Comment: Do you have any errors on console? From my check it seems that the input is not found and `click` method is undefined.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a working plnkr.

Comment: @Dvir There are no errors but $scope.browse isn't being triggered at all with the timeout I do get the console.log however each click register about a 100 logs and the 2nd line with the input type seems not to be working. So I think you are right that the input element is not present but it does show up on the page.

Any solutions?

Comment: Haha the infinity loop is because you are compiling the element that's already has the directive. It's renders the directive everytime the compile function has been called.

Comment: Try to post the code on jsFiddle or something so we'll be able to help you. It's a little messy and waste of time to to that on my own if you want quick answer :)

Comment: you were defining your module incorrectly, have fixed it now

Comment: @adarren The module definition was correct as because this is being based on the angularjs-cordova package where the module is registered originally through another file.

Comment: @AmitPakhira ah ok, makes sense, it's helpful for people to answer your questions with a working snippet though :) I hope you can build on my answer below

Answer (score 0):

So I wouldn't recommend this approach to toggling the visibility of elements, it's something that's better handled in the template logic.

But to get you started I've taken your code and amended it somewhat (https://jsbin.com/negawu)

```
angular
    .module('test-template', [])
    .directive('testTemplateBricks', [
    '$compile',
    '$timeout',
        function($compile,$timeout) {
            return {
               restrict: 'A',
               template: '<input type="file" class="browse-file"/>' + 
                         '<button class="btn btn-info" ng-show="showImage">' + 
                           '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" ng-click="browse()"></span>' + 
                         '</button>' + 
                         '<button class="btn btn-info" ng-show="showText">' + 
                           '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>' + 
                         '</button>',
                link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {

                    $scope.showImage = false;
                    $scope.showText = false;

                    if (iAttrs.needImg == "true") {
                        $scope.showImage = true;
                    }

                    if (iAttrs.needTxt == "true") {
                        $scope.showText = true;
                    }

                    $scope.browse = function() {      
                      console.log("browsing");
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```